# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

I have this error on line 28 which is below.

```
private loadText() { $this->text = $wiki->getpage($this->page);}
```

The surrounding code can be seen below

```
public function parse() { $this->parser = new parser($page,$this->getText()); $this->parser->parse();}
// private functions
private loadText() { $this->text = $wiki->getpage($this->page);} 
private parseNamespace(){...
```

I have can't see the problem and my only guess is that it is something to do with $this->

Comment: Everytime I read "PHP Parse error" in the title of a SO-question I think to myself: "Why don't you use an IDE?" So, why don't you use and IDE, that marks syntax error right in the editor pane?

Comment: what PHP IDE would you suggest?

Comment: Any ;) It's completely up to you. I don't know a PHP-IDE, that is _not_ able to find syntax errors. So there are (probably incomplete) Eclipse/PDT, Netbeans, PhpStorm (my personal favorite) and many others I don't remember yet.

Comment: Aptana Studio 3 is awesome

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your forgot `function` after *every* `private`-keyword. Interestingly you did it right for the one `public` method.